# Increase product stock on custom order status in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, stock

So. I'm trying to create a new order status with PHP, I need that new status to increase the stock of the product that are list in that order, when I do it, it doesn't work, never change anything, even if I attach it to an increase stock hook of WooCommerce.

I tried different things:

Option 1

```php
function wc_maybe_increase_stock_levels1() {
    if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] === 'mark_compra_proveedor' && isset($_GET['order_id'])) {
        $order_id = intval($_GET['order_id']);
        $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

        if (!$order) {
            return;
        }

        $stock_reduced = $order->get_data_store()->get_stock_reduced($order_id);
        $trigger_increase = (bool) $stock_reduced;

        // Only continue if we're increasing stock.
        if (!$trigger_increase) {
            return;
        }

        wc_increase_stock_levels($order);

        // Ensure stock is not marked as "reduced" anymore.
        $order->get_data_store()->set_stock_reduced($order_id, false);
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_mark_compra_proveedor', 'wc_maybe_increase_stock_levels1');`
```

Option 2

```php
/**
 * Función para sumar la cantidad de productos de un pedido al inventario cuando se guarda con el estado "wc-compra-proveedor".
 *
 * @param int $order_id El ID del pedido que se guarda.
 */
function sumar_al_inventario_al_guardar_pedido($order_id) {
    // Obtenemos el objeto del pedido
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    // Verificamos si el pedido tiene el estado "wc-compra-proveedor"
    if ($order && $order->get_status() === 'wc-compra-proveedor') {
        // Recorremos los productos en el pedido y ajustamos el inventario
        foreach ($order->get_items() as $item) {
            $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
            $quantity = $item->get_quantity();

            // Obtén la cantidad actual en inventario del producto
            $current_stock = get_post_meta($product_id, '_stock', true);

            // Calcula la nueva cantidad en inventario sumando la cantidad del pedido
            $new_stock = $current_stock + $quantity;

            // Actualiza la cantidad en inventario del producto
            update_post_meta($product_id, '_stock', max(0, $new_stock)); // Aseguramos que no sea negativo
            update_post_meta($product_id, '_manage_stock', 'yes'); // Habilitamos la gestión de inventario
        }
    }
}

// Hook para ejecutar la función al guardar un pedido
add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'sumar_al_inventario_al_guardar_pedido');`
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following instead, that will increase related product(s) stock levels when the order is set to "compra-proveedor" status:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_compra-proveedor', 'purchase_supplier_order_increase_stock_levels');
function purchase_supplier_order_increase_stock_levels( $order_id, $order ) {
    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) { 
        $item_quantity  = $item->get_quantity(); // Order item quantity
        $product        = $item->get_product(); // Product object

        $stock_quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity(); // product stock quantity

        if ( ! $product->get_manage_stock() ) {
            $product->set_manage_stock( true ); // Enable stock management if not set
        }
        $product->set_stock_quantity( $stock_quantity + $item_quantity ); // updated stock quantity
        $product->set_stock_status(); // update stock status to 'instock'       
        $product->save(); // save product changes

        $order->set_order_stock_reduced(true); // Mark order as stock reduced (trick)
        $order->save(); // save order changes (increase stock)
    }
}
```

It should work.